# Will the closure of Gfycat affect MO?

Tags: discussion, hyperlinks, images

[Gfycat](https://gfycat.com/) is a hosting service for (animated) GIF files, which [will close on September 1st, 2023](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2023/07/the-link-rot-spreads-gif-hosting-site-gfycat-shutting-down-sept-1/). Since some MO users might have included GIF files hosted on Gfycat in their posts, does the service's closure affect us? How did the Imgur closure get solved?

Comment: Searching for url:"\*gfycat\*" [9 results on Mathematics](https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3a%22*gfycat*%22) and [921 results network-wide](https://stackexchange.com/search?q=url%3a%22*gfycat*%22&pagesize=50&page=18) but [no results on MO](https://mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3A%22*gfycat*%22) (and a [single result on meta](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/search?q=url%3A%22*gfycat*%22)).

Comment: Since you asked about Imgur, here is a link to the previous discussion: [Imgur will remove some content soon. Does MathOverflow need to save images?](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/q/5638)
Tangentially, the tag ([meta-tag:images]) seems to be suitable for this question, too.

Comment: A corresponding post on [math.meta.se]: [Will the closure of Gfycat affect MSE?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/35824)

Comment: I knew that a site being this rude to cats couldn't survive for too long.

Comment: @darijgrinberg, [re](https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/5708/will-the-closure-of-gfycat-affect-mo#comment28853_5708), just read it as the helpful reminder "Go feed your cat", and all is well again.